# how to list all the email subject in GMail?

Tags: python, email

I want to list all the email subject in my gmail account.

```
import imaplib
import email
user="xxxx"
password="yyyy"
con=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
con.login(user,password)
num=int(con.select("[Gmail]/&YkBnCZCuTvY-")[1][0])
```

The num is 1200,there are 1200 emails in my gmail account.
I want to list all  the email subject.If i want to get the first email subject ,

```
result,data=con.fetch(b'1', '(RFC822)')
print email.message_from_string(data[0][1])["Subject"]
```

The two lines can get it.
But i can't list all the email subject as the following,how to fix it?

```
for item in range(num+1):
    result,data=con.fetch(str(item), '(RFC822)')
    print email.message_from_string(data[0][1])["Subject"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modifying your range in your for loop.  I believe the message ids in fetch() are '1 based'

```
for item in range(1,num+1):
```